# Regular expression to validate string like "1/2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I need to match only strings that include one character / between numbers or integer numbers.

Examples:

```
1 YES
1/2 YES
some_text NO
some/test NO
some NO
2///2 NO
/12 NO
1/2/ NO
1.2/3 NO
```

Edit:
By rubular.com i`m tried to check this regex: `/\d+(\/\d+)?`

How regex should looks like?

Comment: *"include / or integer number"*, So all of these are acceptable: `1/`, `/2`, `////2`, `1/2/3`, `1//2`, ... If not, please edit your question and specify your requirements more precisely. Also, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only including whole numbers or fractions:

```
\d+(\/\d+)?
```

If you also want to allow decimals:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?(\/\d+(\.\d+)?)?
```

**Edit:** Note that I'm making a lot of assumptions about what you really want.  Bart Kiers's comments to your question are very important -- I took the liberty of assuming that what you want is numbers. If that isn't true, please clarify the question.

**Edit2:** I'm also making one more important assumption. Your question says "strings that **include** / or integer number." If you want to make sure that the string is ONLY a number and nothing else, then add `^` to the beginning of the line and `$` to the end. Example:

```
^\d+(\/\d+)?$
```

Comment: Note that this answer assumes the regex engine works with delimiters (`/`, in this case). Regex does not mandate one to escape the `/`.

Comment: You need to add anchors to your regexes, otherwise it will match e.g. "Foobar1"

Comment: @stema At first I added them, but then I removed them because the OP says "strings that **include** / or integer number." If he spoke correctly, then "foobar1" IS valid. I'll add a note to make that clear.

Comment: The OP says "some/test NO" if you take ""strings that include / or integer number." literally this should be true. So the OP does not describe clearly what he wants, but +1 to you, your answer should now cover most cases.